# vuejs onclick event to return item id in v-for loop

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I need to display item id in a v-for which is currently returning undefined at console:
here is the code:

```
            <ul class="list-group-item" v-for="(st,index) in stock">
             <li @click="changeMenu(st)">{{st.code}}</li> 
              </ul>
         <script>
     changeMenu(obj){
         this.item_name= obj.value;
         console.log(obj.value);
          },
     </script>
```

And the test data:

```
[ { "id": 1, "code": "m009", "description": "flavour", "has_conversions": 0, "name": "milk", "selling_tax": 16, "selling_uom": null, "stocking_uom": 1, "prices": [ { "stock_item_id": 1, "unit_conversion_id": 1, "inclusive_price": 250 } ], "stock": null, "conversions": [] }, { "id": 2, "code": "w3455", "description": "good", "has_conversions": 0, "name": "wheat", "selling_tax": 16, "selling_uom": null, "stocking_uom": 1, "prices": [ { "stock_item_id": 2, "unit_conversion_id": 1, "inclusive_price": 155 } ], "stock": null, "conversions": [] },
```

Answer (score -1):

2 things. First the v-for should be on the `<li>` not the `<ul>`. Second, the object that you are getting passed into that method is the full object from your list.

Without much else, it is hard to decipher what you are trying to achieve.